# Getting Attribute Error: 'Token' object has no attribute 'get_name'

Tags: python, mysql

So I am trying optimize a given SQL query as shown below:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, POSITION
FROM EMPLOYEE E, JOBHISTORY J
WHERE E. EMPNO = J. EMPNO
AND STARTDATE <= ENDDATE
AND SALARY <= 3000;
```

Here I would like to remove the Start and End dates so the user will simply type as follows and then get the result:

```
    SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, POSITION
    FROM EMPLOYEE E, JOBHISTORY J
    WHERE E. EMPNO = J. EMPNO
    AND SALARY <= 3000;
```

I initially started to write my own parser in python but got really stumped and decided look around and found out about the library "sqlparse", in the library they had the function get_names() being used part of the token function however when implementing it in my code I keep getting the error AttributeError 'Token' object has no attribute 'get_name' so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my Python code:

```
import sqlparse
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example query
query = "SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, POSITION FROM EMPLOYEE E, JOBHISTORY J WHERE E.EMPNO = J.EMPNO AND STARTDATE <= ENDDATE AND SALARY <= 3000"

# parse the query
parsed_query = sqlparse.parse(query)[0]
select_stmt = parsed_query.tokens[0]

# extract the tables and conditions from the query
tables = []
conditions = []
for token in parsed_query.tokens:
    if isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.IdentifierList):
        for T in token.get_identifiers():
            tables.append(T.get_name())
    elif isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.Where):
        for condition in token.tokens:
            if isinstance(condition, sqlparse.sql.Comparison):
                conditions.append(condition)

# remove unnecessary conditions
new_conditions = []
for condition in conditions:
    if "startdate" not in condition.normalized:
        new_conditions.append(condition)
conditions = new_conditions

# generate query tree
G = nx.Graph()
for table in tables:
    G.add_node(table)
for condition in conditions:
    table1 = condition.left.get_name()
    table2 = condition.right.get_name()
    G.add_edge(table1, table2)

# visualize query tree
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

# generate optimized query
new_query = select_stmt.to_unicode()
new_query += " FROM " + ", ".join(tables)
new_query += " WHERE " + " AND ".join([str(condition) for condition in conditions])
print(new_query)
```

Comment: is it because the function is `get_names` with an s and not `get_name`?

Answer (score 1):

Because Token does not have a get_name attribute, you should make a judgment, for example, POSITION is sqlparse.sql.Token not sqlparse.sql.Identifier

```
print(type(T), T)
if isinstance(T, sqlparse.sql.Identifier):
    tables.append(T.get_name())
```

condition.left condition.right also for similar reasons